QZ Tray Print Server - How to replace default certs that are presented to clients in wss:// connections?
For the QZ Tray print server, how can I just install known good certificates that I already have generated with qz-tray-console.exe, without regenerating new ones, so that it presents those to the client instead?
If I run qz-tray-console.exe certgen --host [ip_address] It generates and installs a NEW set of certificates which are presented to the client during wss connection, but I don't want new certificates to be installed.

Yes, thank you, @tresf, I genuinely don't understand any comment-less downvoting of a question. If the question is not clear, I am willing to add more info. I read the instructions at the link below many times before posting here. I did not know the password was in the qz-tray.properties file, and I was unclear as to whether this was the right command due to that and the "manually shimming" language. Other instructions for this app advise adding the cert as part of software code, so I thought that might be what was meant by "manual shimming". Apologies if I was the only one confused by this.

As you've observed, certgen parameter --host is intended for the generation of a self-signed certificate.
If instead you want to provide your own certificate, you will instead use the --cert parameter per: https://qz.io/docs/print-server#trusted-ca-certificate
Basic Syntax
# pem/der
java -jar qz-tray.jar certgen --key "privkey.pem" --cert "fullchain.pem"

# pfx/pkcs#12
java -jar qz-tray.jar certgen --pfx "mycert.pfx" --pass "12345"

Windows:

qz-tray-console.exe certgen [...]

Mac:

"/Applications/QZ Tray.app/Contents/MacOS/QZ Tray" certgen [...]

Linux:

/opt/qz-tray/qz-tray certgen [...]

This information is also available via --help certgen, quoting:
Usage: java -jar qz-tray.jar (command)
  certgen                     Performs certificate generation and registration for proper HTTPS support.
                                java -jar qz-tray.jar certgen [--key key.pem --cert cert.pem] [--pfx cert.pfx --pass 12345] [--host "list;of;hosts"]
OPTIONS
  --host, --hosts             Semicolon-delimited hostnames and/or IP addresses to generate the HTTPS certificate for.
  --cert, -c                  Path to a stand-alone HTTPS certificate
  --key, -k                   Path to a stand-alone HTTPS private key
  --pfx, --pkcs12             Path to a paired HTTPS private key and certificate in PKCS#12 format.
  --pass, -p                  Password for decoding private key.


The instructions on the website advise "manually shimming" the 3rd party certificates "into the software". Do the commands under "Basic Syntax" complete this "manual shimming", or is there something more needed (besides ensuring the root cert is trusted by clients)?

Yes, those are the manual steps.  If the certificate is trusted by most browsers, this step should do as expected.  Some implied steps:  1. Must be run as elevated user. 2. Must restart QZ Tray after the command succeeds.

I tried it using a key generated by QZTray, but it says keystore password was incorrect.
java -jar qz-tray.jar certgen --pfx "qz-tray.p12" --pass '12345'

If the software generated it, the password should be located in the qz-tray.properties file (e.g. C:\Program Files\QZ Tray\qz.-tray.properties).  If the password has been overwritten since then or if the password is missing, there's little that can be done retroactively about that (as is the nature with most forgotten passwords).

I used the password successfully in a test environment. If I am using the cert generated by QZ Tray, does the certgen command have to be run for both root-ca.p12 and qz-tray.p12 ?

Good question.  The certificate provided with QZ Tray is only good for 825 days per https://support.apple.com/en-us/103769.    If you have luck deploying the root-ca.p12 file that's much preferred (that one is good for 200 years), but some browsers may not like this, so proceed at your own risk.  Only one certificate can be installed at a given time.

I tested it today, and it only worked when I used the qz-tray.p12 file, which is fine for now. Thanks!
